# Help with WordPress search

Tags: search, directory, location-search

i am creating a directory using WP, and need to allow customers to be able to search by industry and sector, like here http://www.checkatrade.com/

I will be setting these up through two taxonomies: 1: Industry 2) Location

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What have you tried?  The native search functions in WP are pretty flexible.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page

Comment: @jdm2112 I wouldn't even no where to start, i no it passes a query through the url but how can query to different taxonomies, and only get the result that fits both. I have no idea where to even start.

Comment: I would be happy to guide you on this somewhat but it would require some details for me to provide any useful info.  Are you using a custom post type with your taxonomies or the predefined posts?  I could be wrong but if your form will receive two tax values, you can create a custom tax query with those values to display on the results page.  Depending on your PHP comfort level, you may simply wish to use a plugin.  Relevanssi (I have no personal experience with it) appears to support tax search queries out of the box.  http://www.relevanssi.com/features/

Comment: @jdm2112 Yep a separate post types with two taxonomies, sector and location. I no how to use wp_Query to do a tax query what you mean? Would you recommend doing it this way? Or would you do it through the url?

Comment: You can pass the values in the URL (i.e. POST), as global variables or probably other methods I'm not aware of.  Is your challenge designing the query for the results list or where exactly?